# Aglio Render Markdown after Request / Response section

Tags: apiblueprint, aglio

Here's a snippet of my apib document.
Essentially, I want to be able to put additional descriptive information after the Request and Response sections, however this information is not rendered. Instead any further text under a new heading is interpreted as part of the response 200 section. I would like to be able to put a table in the Errors section, so this data would ideally be markdown rendered. Is this possible with aglio? 
Thanks!

```
#### Rate Limiting

This endpoint allows 20 requests per hour.

+ Request (application/json)
    + Attributes (object)
        + id (number)

+ Response 200 (application/json)
    + Attributes (object)
        + status: success (string)

### Errors

Table of error codes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cameron, this is only currently possible within the description section before the request/response pairs. For example:

```
## My Resource [/foo]

### My Action [GET]

#### Rate Limiting

This endpoint allows 20 requests per hour.

#### Errors

Table of error codes

+ Request (application/json)
    + Attributes (object)
        + id (number)

+ Response 200 (application/json)
    + Attributes (object)
        + status: success (string)
```

Alternatively, you could hard code this sort of information in a custom template which would give you full control over what goes where. The reason I say "hard code" is because the API Blueprint parser is seeing your text as belonging to the response rather than the action or example, and I can't modify that behavior within Aglio. You could open a ticket on the upstream [API Blueprint](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint) repository to request such a feature or use the workaround above.

One last note - you can describe 400 and 500 level responses as request/response pairs. Since the request/response pairs are rendered in the order given in the document you can ensure the error examples show up last.